# lavaan: how to fix residual correlation to 1

Tags: r, r-lavaan

**Question: how do you set a residual correlation (covariance between latent variables) to 1 in `lavaan`?**

I am running a multitrait-multimethod analysis, replicating the method Barbara Byrne describes for `Mplus` users (chapter 10: http://books.google.com/books/about/Structural_Equation_Modeling_With_Mplus.html?id=u58MPwAACAAJ). This method involves creating four models. My problem involves the third and fourth of these models, which require you to set latent variable correlations to 1.

Here's my code for the third model:

```
mtmm3 <- '
method1 =~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 
method2 =~ v5 + v6 + v7 + v8
method3 =~ v9 + v10 + v11
trait1 =~ v1 + v5 + v9
trait2 =~ v2 + v6 + v10
trait3 =~ v3 + v7 + v11
trait4 =~ v4 + v8
trait1 ~~ 1*trait2
trait1 ~~ 1*trait3
trait1 ~~ 1*trait4
trait2 ~~ 1*trait3
trait2 ~~ 1*trait4
trait3 ~~ 1*trait4
method1 ~~ method2 + method3
method2 ~~ method3
trait1 ~~ 0*method1
trait1 ~~ 0*method2
trait1 ~~ 0*method3
trait2 ~~ 0*method1
trait2 ~~ 0*method2
trait2 ~~ 0*method3
trait3 ~~ 0*method1
trait3 ~~ 0*method2
trait3 ~~ 0*method3
trait4 ~~ 0*method1
trait4 ~~ 0*method2
trait4 ~~ 0*method3
'
```

The problem arises with this part of the code:

```
trait1 ~~ 1*trait2
trait1 ~~ 1*trait3
trait1 ~~ 1*trait4
trait2 ~~ 1*trait3
trait2 ~~ 1*trait4
trait3 ~~ 1*trait4
```

`lavaan` interprets the `1*` as a request for group-level analysis. Two groups are summarized in the output for this model. I don't want to do group-level analysis; I just want perfectly correlated trait-factors.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Perfectly correlated latent factors are formed by making **one latent factor** instead of multiple latent factors. So, the new syntax looks like this:

```
mtmm3 <- '
method1 =~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 
method2 =~ v5 + v6 + v7 + v8
method3 =~ v9 + v10 + v11
traits =~ v1 + v5 + v9 + 
    v2 + v6 + v10 + 
    v3 + v7 + v11 +
    v4 + v8
method1 ~~ method2 + method3
method2 ~~ method3
traits ~~ 0*method1
traits ~~ 0*method2
traits ~~ 0*method3
'
```